# why is $\lim f_{n} = \lim \inf f$?

Tags: proof-explanation, limsup-and-liminf

I was reading the solution to this problem

[Problem about limit of Lebesgue integral over a measurable set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184902/problem-about-limit-of-lebesgue-)
integral-over-a-measurable-set?noredirect=1&lq=1

And I did not understand why in the fifth line he substituted $\lim f_{n}$ by  $\lim \inf f$ .... could anyone explain this for me?

Comment: Because if a sequence has a limit then this limit equals to the $\liminf$.

Comment: If a $\lim$ of a sequence exists, it equals the $\liminf$.

Comment: but in my question the $\lim \inf$ is of $f$ but the limit is of $f_{n}$ @HansEngler

Comment: I know that $\lim \inf$ is the smallest accumulation point is this the reason of the correctness of your first equality ? Also why it is not equal $\lim \sup$? or it is also  equal to it? @Mark

Comment: It also equals to the $\limsup$. But to use Fatou's lemma you need $\liminf$, that's why it was used in that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality $\lim_nf_n=\liminf_nf_n$ is trivially true. And then one can apply [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma):$$\int_E\liminf_nf_n\leqslant\liminf_n\int_Ef_n.$$

Comment: I know that $\lim \inf$ is the smallest accumulation point is this the reason of the correctness of your first equality ? Also why it is not equal $\lim \sup$? or it is also  equal to it?

Comment: but in my question the $\lim \inf$ is of $f$ but the limit is of $f_{n}$

Comment: For **any** convergent sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ of real numbers we have$$\lim_na_n=\liminf_na_n=\limsup_na_n.$$

Comment: And in that answer $\liminf_nf$ is a typo. It should be $\liminf_nf_n$.

Comment: got it! thank you very much!